# ASP.NET Webforms and URL encoding

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, unicode, get, webforms

I'm having issues with GET parameters and ASP.NET. I've got one parameter with a value which has non-ASCII characters (**"Físico"**). When ASP.NET generates the form, it has the action set to

```
<form method="post" action="SomePage.aspx?query=F%u00edsico">
```

It doesn't seem like the string is being properly URL encoded by ASP.NET. This is causing issues with jQuery UI ("malformed URI"). Am I missing anything? Shouldn't the browser be properly encoding the URL and shouldn't ASP.NET properly encode it when it generates the form?

Comment: Show the code you use to generate the action of the form.

Comment: I do not generate the action of the form, I merely link to SomePage.aspx?query=Físico. ASP.NET then generates its' form (as usual).

Comment: Got it, was able to duplicate the issue.

Comment: I filed a bug against ASP.NET for this.  Sorry for the wonky behavior on our part. :(

As a workaround, you could set Form.Action = Request.RawUrl; from Page_Load().  It's a slightly simpler form of Hanlet's solution.

Comment: Can you put the `query` parameter in a hidden input, to avoid the incorrect query encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on the `Page_Load` event as a work around:

**Vb.Net**

```
Dim unicode As UnicodeEncoding = New UnicodeEncoding
form1.Action = unicode.GetString(unicode.GetBytes(Request.Url.ToString()))
```

**c#**

```
UnicodeEncoding unicode = new UnicodeEncoding();
form1.Action = unicode.GetString(unicode.GetBytes(Request.Url.ToString()));
```

that query string is being encoded to unicode because of the tilde in the `í`